# Custom alert not showing - React

Tags: reactjs, django, react-redux, frontend

I am currently following a tutorial for a Django + React project.

When a user tries to login with the wrong credentials, an alert "error" should popup, and when the user manages to login a "success" alert should appear as well. The login logic works fine, but I don't get any alert (they are custom alerts btw).

**login :**

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken"

export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

    try {
        const res = await 
          axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/token/', 
            body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(setAlert('Authenticated successfully', 'success'));
    }
    catch(err) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
        });

        dispatch(setAlert('Error Authenticating', 'error'));
    }
};
```

**Alert :**

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { SET_ALERT, REMOVE_ALERT } from './types';

export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => dispatch => {
    const id = uuid();
    dispatch({
        type: SET_ALERT,
        payload: { msg, alertType, id }
    });

    setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
}
```

**Checking state**

```
import { login } from '../actions/auth';


const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      login(email, password);
  };

  if (isAuthenticated)
        return <Navigate to='/' />;
    
    return (
          <div> The form is in there </div>
    );
};

Login.propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

And here is what I get from Redux dev tools :

[image: Redux screenshot]

I have checked import and variables names, and I can't find an answer anywhere else.

Have a nice day !

Comment: why have you added the alert in `dispatch` ? you can just show the alert in the page it self .

Comment: I believe that's what I did with `catch(err) { ... dispatch(setAlert('Error..'));`
But as I am quite new to react and JS I might be mistaken and wrong about the use of dispatch

Comment: Could you also add your authentication screen code if possible? (Or whichever file you are checking state to get the alert information)

Comment: Yes ! I edited the post

Comment: @Guillaume-ds yes , please don't make it more complex ,when you receive the response from backend just trigger an Alert Class and display the success or the error accordingly

Comment: Well after trying for a few hours I am capitulating and going back to the simple alert. The solution works with simple alerts, so the problem must be linked to the setAlert. It's quite frustrating not to know the reason !!

Comment: @Guillaume-ds even if you crack and resolve this issue , it will be a bad application solution . use redux when you have data to share between multiple components and when it difficult  to manage with `useState`. try to read more on redux where and when to apply it :)

Comment: @ShoyebMemon Thanks for your feed back; I'll keep that in mind ! I'am a complete newby to React, but it's exciting to see all the possibilities once you added a frontend framework to django !

Comment: @Guillaume-ds no worries :) happy coding.